# Can we become infected with a virus that reaches our body in a bacterium?

Tags: virus, bacteria

I read that bacteria can be infected by viruses. Are there viruses that affect both organisms (bacteria and humans)? Is it possible to get a virus from a bacterial infection (the bacteria is the carrier of the virus)?